# Export questions and answers from a Stack Overflow Teams site

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams

Is it possible to export all questions and answers from a Basic Stack Overflow Teams account?

I can see the Stack Exchange Data Explorer, but I believe this just searches the public sites and won't work for a private 'teams' one.

Is this available in Basic or is something you need Enterprise and the API for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done by any team admin via the Settings section within the team. While viewing the Settings, click on 'Account information' under the 'Billing' section. You'll then be presented with your account information. On this page, you'll notice a 'Download data' option off to the right side.

Upon clicking this, data will be downloaded in a ZIP file. Upon expansion of this ZIP file, you will see a series of JSON files, containing information regarding: Badges, Comments, Images, Posts, Tags, Users, and Votes.

Comment: Was this removed? I don't see 'Account information'. I'm currently trying out the free basic version. Do I need to enter billing information to have access to this?

Comment: @Juice But it doesn't contain the answers. How do i get the answers?

Comment: @indraneel Both questions and answers are contained in posts.json.

Comment: I don't see this feature anymore.. :(

Comment: @JeroenKnoops I'm still seeing the option. If you don't, please open a ticket with us at support at StackOverflow dot com.

Comment: Would be useful with something like a JSON -> PDF converter